# JavaScript not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have a page where in a div HTMl is loaded from another page. In the parent page, I have javascript which has elements that apply to the dynamic content (such as mouseover animate, etc.). I have been trying to make it work for quite a few hours now but it just won't work. No JS errors in the Chrome developer tools. Can anyone help?

For example on the parent page's javascript I have:

```
jQuery("ul#nav li.page a").on('mouseover', '.item', function () {
    jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 0)"
    }, 500);
    jQuery(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -35px)"
    }, 750);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -120px)"
    }, 750)
});
```

and the 'child' page where HTML is loaded from

```
<li class="page"><a href="home" style="margin:0 22px 0 0" class="item">Home</a></li>
<li class="page"><a href="about" class="item">About Us</a></li>
<li class="page"><a href="store" class="item">Store</a></li>
<li class="page"><a href="news" class="item">News</a></li>
<li class="page"><a href="contact" style="margin:0 0 0 22px" class="item">Contact</a></li>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is `this` in your code?

Comment: @akonsu sorry about that -- forgot one line of code. should be good now.

Comment: how you are transacting the animation,on what event you are calling this animation.i am not sure of the scenario but check live and delegate method in jquery api.

Comment: The javascript works fine on a static page (without dynamic load), so the () positions should be fine. There is also the background position jquery plugin that goes along with this, but that should be fine as well (unmodified)... any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by child page? Are you loading an iframe in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using 'delegate' method instead of 'on'.

```
jQuery(body).delegate('ul#nav li.page a', 'mouseover', function () {
    jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 0)"
    }, 500);
    jQuery(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -35px)"
    }, 750);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -120px)"
    }, 750)
});
```

Comment: Perfect, awesome! The other answers may work as well, but this one was the first to try and works just like it should. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to attach .on action to a dynamic element, you attach it to the $(document) instead.
and when the new elements are loaded the action is already there.

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseover', 'ul#nav li.page a', function () {
    jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 0)"
    }, 500);
    jQuery(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -35px)"
    }, 750);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -120px)"
    }, 750)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
jQuery("ul#nav li.page a").on('mouseover', '.item', function () {
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -35px)"
    }, 750);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 -120px)"
    }, 750)
});
```